# JavaScript to Paste from Clipboard then Send Enter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple Chrome extension to satisfy some users needs, but am having difficulty doing so.  I've already created the required manifest.json and .js files, but am having trouble with the coding.

**JS Code I'm Trying to Create**
The extension should add an option to Chrome's context menu so that if a web page field / address bar is right clicked on, there is a "Paste & Enter" option which pastes whatever text is in the clipboard then sends an "Enter" keystroke.

The closest code I've found online for at least the pasting part [on this post](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/) - however - I've tried adding it to my background.js file and cannot get it to work.

Any assistance would be more than helpful - Thanks!

Also, do any web / software tools exist which may assist in creating things like this or is the best bet still a text editor?

Comment: Could you post the code you've developed so far? Also, _I've tried adding it to my background.js file and cannot get it to work_; could you add more information?

Comment: Also post `manifest.json`, I suspect there's no [clipboardRead](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) permission.